# Angular - Difference between "optimization" and "buildOptimizer" in the build config (angular.json)

Tags: angular, build

Can someone explain me exactly the difference between those two flags (`optimization` and `buildOptimizer`) defined in the build config `angular.json` during the build process when I execute `ng build`?
The official [build documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build) isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**buildOptimizer** optimizes the transpilation of TS to JS (remove unused code, add tslib,..)
More detailed explanation in the readme of the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer

**optimization flag** I think this one indicates the execution of some Webpack plugins. As in what to do with the JS after the buildOptimizer.

More about optimization flag [here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration)

Comment: Gotcha. Very informative. Thank you for your fast respond!

Comment: Note: For the new esbuild builder the `buildOptimizer` option does nothing and must be removed: https://angular.io/guide/esbuild#using-the-application-builder